# Cognito Role and AWS S3 Bucket policy for mobile and web access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

Our goal is to create S3 bucket and IAM role policies that will only allow S3 access to our logged in users.

We are hosting private files on an S3 bucket that will be accessed from both a web and mobile app. We are attempting to add a layer of security with Amazon Cognito, using an unauthenticated role, so that any users signed into our application can access the S3 bucket.

Using the AWS-SDK for JS and following the basic `AWS.config.credentials` setup, we can see 1 identity accessed and the number of syncs in our Amazon Cognito Identity Dashboard. Since we seem to be connecting to the IdentityPool, I'm thinking that our policies may need some tweaking so that logged in users that have the unauthenticated Cognito role can access the S3 bucket.

IAM Role policy for Cognito_IdentityPoolUnauth_Role

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "SID_NUMBER",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::OUR_BUCKET_NAME/*"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

S3 BUCKET POLICY

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "http referer policy example",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::IAM_NUMBER:role/Cognito_IdentityPoolUnauth_Role"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::OUR_BUCKET_NAME/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to access your files directly from the browser after getting Cognito credentials or programmatically using the javscript sdk getObject?

Comment: @behrooziAWS i was trying to access my files directly from the browser.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I am also trying to allow my Cognito users to access s3 bucket files, without signed url. I don't want to make a getObject call to get the token and then render image.

Answer (score 5):

When you attempt to access the files directly from the browser, no credentials are sent with the request.  It has the same effect as trying to hit S3 directly without having any code to get credentials from Cognito.  In order to use the Cognito credentials, you need to make the request using the javascript SDK.  Below is a example request using the  javascript SDK taken from [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html#Getting_a_pre-signed_URL_for_a_getObject_operation)

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var params = {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'myKey'};
s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function (err, url) {
  console.log("The URL is", url);
});
```

If you call this after getting Cognito credentials, it will use Cognito credentials to create a signed url to access the key myKey in bucket myBucket.  You can take an approach similar to this to listObjects in your bucket and then generate signed urls (signed with Cognito credentials) that your end users can click on to view the contents of each key in your bucket.